# How do I correctly configure ExtReact to run custom elements in Edge and IE?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, extjs, microsoft-edge, extreact

I'm a little worried this is a dumb issue that I'm running into but here goes:

I just created an ExtReact app following the tutorial [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/7.2.0/guides/getting_started/creating_ext_react_app_modern.html). Without changing any code I'm seeing the following error in Edge:
[image: Error Screenshot]

The app loads fine in Firefox and Chrome but not Edge or IE. Obviously it has to do with custom elements but I don't know what else I'm missing or if I've misconfigured something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [webcomponents polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs)

Comment: Thanks! Also discovered I'm running an old version of Edge.